# Internet Explorer performance problems

Tags: javascript, html, performance, internet-explorer, jsp

I have a JSP page with a lot of DOM objects and JavaScript code. The page rendering is quite slow, so I did some time measurements and cross browser comparisons:

- Firefox renders page within 8.33s, which is okay for the amount of
  data
- Internet Explorer renders page within 22.65s, which is too slow!

After this I did a refactoring of my JavaScript code and won about 1 - 2 seconds. This is nice but still too slow. So wanted to check what happens when I remove all my JavaScript source code from JSP. Result was that I won about 2 seconds. ( = JavaScript execution time)

Surprinsingly I see some HTML content very fast but Internet Explorer needs about 20 seconds to render all the content before the $(document).ready() event is triggered.

So I checked what happens when I completely disable JavaScript and tested again. Then Internet Explorer only had 7.2 seconds to render.

This is strange, because I see that the JS execution time does generally take 2 seconds.

Can anybody explain to my why internet explorer is nearly 3 times slower than firefox and why Internet Explorer is such fast with deactivated JavaScript?

Comment: What is your code doing? Where is it loading from? What versions of the browsers?

Comment: Ask MS, we all wanna know! To be serious IMO this is too vague to be a SO question (for example...what are you doing in your code?). If I can suggest something I would **split computation into discrete chunks**. Total time won't be lower (it may even be longer) but users won't have perception of a long operation because they'll get data step by step (and probably faster than time they need to read it).

Comment: I tested with IE9,IE10,IE11 and Firefox27. Most of the operations are initilisation of jquery-ui components (tooltip, dialogs, tablesorter), hide and show content and colorize elements regarding to their state.

Comment: Yes I agree, I just thought that maybe somebody can share its experience or has a good idea how I can reduce the gap between IE and Firefox. I already tried to split up my JavaScript code so that several initializations are only done when the result is also visible.

Comment: Honestly I can't imagine any JavaScript code that to initialize UI will spend 20 seconds (even on IE). Of course if (for example) you have a table with 10000 rows then tablesorter will take very long time to do its job (move it to an asynchronous AJAX call, for example). That said I would first check which part takes most of time (even 8 seconds without JS are a lot), sorting/paging tables? Downloading images? Downloading data?

Comment: I dont think that the problem is the JavaScript code itself, because it does only take 2 seconds. (The 2 seconds are the maximum and are only when I have very long table lists) But I am confused about the fact that IE has 14 seconds longer to render the whole content. But maybe I just have to live with it.

Comment: 14 seconds? If you're not using a 486SX then it has to be a very HUGE page, even on IE. You should measure rendering time disabling JavaScript, maybe it's not JS code from your page but from an external library...